# If I pass an object to a constructor and then modify that object, will it modify the original? Why?

Tags: java, class

If I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Web {
    WebDriver driver; 
    
    public Web(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
}
```

will `this.driver` used throughout the `Web` class affect the original driver that was passed in? I need them to both reference the same object.

Comment: yes. this is because classes are from reference type. If you want to avoid it use deep clone of the object

Comment: "I need them to both reference the same object" -- yes, when you say `this.driver = driver` you do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Java any object that is not a primitive is passed as a reference. So if you want to have control on the object inside this class or from wherever you called, it is possible. The drawback is that you cannot assume an object will never be changed in you class, unless you create a copy of it (for example with a clone() )

Comment: so in this example, this.driver will be completely different from the original driver?

Comment: No, `this.driver` and `driver` are references to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will.  When a method performs an operation using the reference in `this.driver`, it will be performing an operation on the same `WebDriver` that you passed to the constructor.  If that method modifies the state of the object ... it is the object that you passed in that is being modified.

- Java call semantics are "call by value" aka "pass by value"
- When you pass an object, the value you are passing is the reference to the object.
- Java doesn't make copies of objects implicitly.

In your example code in the question, you are not actually modifying the object that you passed to the constructor.  (But you certainly could ...)

If you don't what the constructor (or some other method of the class) to be *able* to modify the object passed to it, you could:

- pass it an *immutable* object, or
- pass it a copy (or clone) of the original object.

Comment: Yes, I need this.driver to be the same object as driver. when  I change one, I want the other one to change., How should i do this?

Comment: Yes, if you say `this.driver = driver` then your variable `this.driver` will actually be a reference to the same object as `driver`.